# how to do ratcheting using jenkins jacoco plugin

Tags: jenkins, jacoco

Is it possible to do build ratcheting using jenkins jacoco plugin. We want every checkin to atleast have the same or higher code coverage than the previous checkin.

I belive jenkins corbutura provides this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the build fail based on the previous build's coverage, but you can set a baseline and then fail the build if the coverage % drops below that value.  See the attached screen shot.

[image]